# multiple definition error while linking object file and static library

Tags: c++, g++, googletest

I need to mock some of functions in a static library libddrmgr.a in order to write unit test. I implement the mock code on `gtest_ddrmaint_cmds.cpp` and compile it to `gtest_ddrmaint_cmds.o`. 
However, g++ prompt multiple definition error while linking the object file and static library:

```
g++ -g -o ddrmainttest main.o gtest_ddrmaint_cmds.o /walker/external/3rdparty/google/gtest.a /walker/external/3rdparty/google/gmock.a /walker/src/build/SLES/lib/libddrmgr.a -lacl -lxml2 -lpthread -ldl -luuid -lz -lresolv -lcap -lrt --coverage

/walker/src/build/SLES/lib/libddrmgr.a(ddrmgr.o): In function `DDR_Shutdown':
/walker/src/ddrmgr/ddrmgr.cpp:110: multiple definition of `DDR_Shutdown'
gtest_ddrmaint_cmds.o:/walker/src/gunittest/ddrmaint/gtest_ddrmaint_cmds.cpp:16: first defined here
/walker/src/build/SLES/lib/libddrmgr.a(ddrmgr.o): In function `DDR_Init':
/walker/src/ddrmgr/ddrmgr.cpp:38: multiple definition of `DDR_Init'
gtest_ddrmaint_cmds.o:/walker/external/3rdparty/google/gmock-1.7.0/gtest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:443: first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ddrmainttest] Error 1
```

I also wrote a demo program to test if it's OK to override some library owned functions in a object file and it works fine. Can somebody tell me why it prompt error above? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is your question?  it tells you where the problem is.  `first defined here
/walker/src/build/SLES/lib/libddrmgr.a`  If you want further help, post your code.  What exactly else do you expect someone to be able to tell you?

Comment: The most likely answer is there's an unresolved symbol referencing a symbol in the same translation unit where the duplicate symbols are also defined, forcing the inclusion of that translation unit, and hence a duplicate symbol definition.

Comment: You cannot replace individual functions, you have to replace entire objects (object == member of the library).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks! I think you are correct! So how should I do if only want to mock parts of the functions owned by a static library?

Comment: write thin wrappers to the functions you want to call in the library and provide mocks for those wrappers, which you can turn on or off with conditional compilation.

Answer (score 1):

In order to mock functions in C++, you cannot simply redefine them. As you just experience, this leads to `multiple definition` linker errors.

The way to proceed is as Richard Hodges' suggests in his comment, to write a thin wrapper to the library functions you want to use and create mocks for those wrapper objects.

It is well explained in Google Mock [docs](https://github.com/google/googlemock/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#mocking-free-functions):

> It's possible to use Google Mock to mock a free function (i.e. a
>   C-style function or a static method). You just need to rewrite your
>   code to use an interface (abstract class).
>
> Instead of calling a free function (say, OpenFile) directly, introduce
>   an interface for it and have a concrete subclass that calls the free
>   function:
>
> ```
> class FileInterface
> {
> public:
>   ...
>   virtual bool Open(const char* path, const char* mode) = 0;
> };
> class File : public FileInterface
> {
> public:
>   ...
>   virtual bool Open(const char* path, const char* mode)
>   {
>     return OpenFile(path, mode);
>   }
> };
> ```
>
> Your code should talk to FileInterface to open a file. Now it's easy to mock out the function.